# How to read in multiple .csv.gz files at once and append them with pandas

Tags: pandas, csv, append, gzip

I have a directory (`myDir`) that contains 3,169 .csv.gz files.
For example:

```
file1.csv.gz
file2.csv.gz
...
file3169.csv.gz
```

All files have exactly the same layout.

Is it possible to read them all in at once with pandas and collate/append (not merge!!) them?

Comment: `pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob.glob(path_to_your_files)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) instead of `glob`:

```
import pathlib

myDir = pathlib.Path('my_folder')
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in myDir.glob('*.csv.gz')], 
               ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
# Get data file names
path1 = myDir
filenames = glob.glob(myDir + "/*.csv.gz")

dfs = []
for filename in filenames:
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(filename))

# Concatenate all data into one DataFrame
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
display(df)
print(df.info())
```